# Why don’t commits follow the merge-base error?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-submodules

Our process for git is a periodic merge down to our master branch so that the changes can be merged back out to our latest features branches.  Since out latest rounds of merging from one branch to another, we are running into a problem in which the solution is not clear.

We have a repository that has 19 submodules within it. When doing our merging of all the submodules, we see what we believe to be the expected output telling us files being modified, conflicts, etc.  Then when we get to the merge of the “root” repository, everything goes south and we see some of the following output (edited to point out the issues only).

```
warning: Failed to merge submodule projects/foo1 (commits don't follow merge-base)
warning: Failed to merge submodule projects/foo2 (commits don't follow merge-base)
warning: Failed to merge submodule projects/foo3 (not fast-forward)

Found a possible merge resolution for the submodule:
 931a61165f3b2079523a122477fa5f44c123406d: Comment of last merge

If this is correct simply add it to the index for example by using:

 git update-index --cacheinfo 160000 931a61165f3b2079523a122477fa5f44c123406d "projects/foo3"

which will accept this suggestion.
```

Now, we can run the suggested `git update-index` command. It will make git happy for that one submodule, but we have never had to run this before.  The issue is really bad when looking at the foo1 and foo2 submodules in which no help is displayed.

Comment: For each modification of the submodules, did you also commit and push the parent repo?

Comment: Prior to the merge both trees are completely functional without any issue of a missed commit in any submodule.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean that, when you modify a submodule, you must commit and push, then go to the parent, commit and push as well (because the SHA1 of the submodule has changed). I was wondering if you did any modification to those submodules (and if yes, if you did follow the commit-push sequence), before attempting merging the parent repo.

Comment: I have made no changes whatsoever to the branch that I want to merge to.  The action is a clean merge of two known good branches.  The command I am using to run the merge is a simple `git merge main`.  We have merged between these branches before the last time being about 10 days ago without incident.

Comment: I understand, but did you made any change on any branch in any of the submodules? If you merge a submodule, that modifies it, meaning you need at least to go back in the parent repo, and commit, in order to record the new SHA1 of the modified submodule.

Comment: Sorry if I am dragging this out and I appreciate your help.  So are you asking that out of the 19 submodules, I merge foo1, then commit, then add/commit the parent, then move on to foo2?  This would be completely different then how we have been merging for years but I am certainly willing to try anything at this point

Comment: For those browsing to this post, while I wasn't 100% sure what happened, I believe it was due to a user who manually removed the GIT_MERGE files from their root repository and pushed.   By manually merging each submodule, pushing the changes and then in the root submodule running `git commit -i -m"blah" .` did we appear to fix the issue.  Git never claimed that we needed to commit in the root submodule but it appears we did need to.  Subsequent merges so far appear to be working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In case OP's comment below his question disappears:

> For those browsing to this post, while I wasn't 100% sure what happened, I believe it was due to a user who manually removed the GIT_MERGE files from their root repository and pushed. By manually merging each submodule, pushing the changes and then in the root submodule running
>
> ```
> git commit -i -m "blah" .
> ```
>
> did we appear to fix the issue. Git never claimed that we needed to commit in the root submodule but it appears we did need to. Subsequent merges so far appear to be working correctly.